# loading partialview where viewname is set inside ViewBag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

From my controller I'm sending localized view name like

```
string currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
string viewName = string.Empty;
switch (currentCulture)
{
     case "en-US":
       viewName = "en-US.cshtml";
       break;
     case "de-DE":
       viewName = "de-DE.cshtml";
       break;
     case "fr-FR":
       viewName = "fr-FR.cshtml";
       break;
       default:        
 }
ViewBag.LocView = "~/Views/Home/"+viewName;
```

and inside view I want to display using partial like

```
@Html.Partial(@ViewBag.LocView);
```

but this obviously is not ok since I'm getting

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has not applicable method named
>   'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewBag isn't strongly typed and `@Html.Partial` expects a string, so you should be able to:

```
@Html.Partial((string)@ViewBag.LocView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast it to a string data type when calling ViewBag

```
@Html.Partial((string)@ViewBag.LocView)
```